# value too large for defined data type in PHP File

Tags: php

I am trying to include a file in my index page to display the links. Since it will be constant throughout the site I figured I would do the links as a separate file and included them throughout the sit by inserting `@include('includes/site_links.txt')` I tried it with the .php extension upon getting the error and I still get it. The error I am getting is: `Value too large for defined data type in /home/www/DOMAIN_NAME/templates/SITE_NAME/index.php on line 30`

I have `<?php @includes('images/includes/site_links/links.php'); ?>` is what I have on line 30 and in that file is the html for the links that should be on the site. It contains just plain html and a little php.

Is there any difference in PHP behaviours between php 4 and php 5 relating to includes? I have PHP 5.3.2 on my localhost and 4.4.9 on the server, could that be an issue?

Comment: whats on line 30 on index.php?

Comment: What's the filesize of includes/site_links.txt?

Comment: And what's in includes/site_links.txt?

Comment: it was a text file that included the site links that would be constant throughout the site. However I thought the .txt was the issue and I then changed it to the .php and the issue still exists.

Comment: Googling suggests it's not a PHP problem but a problem with your linux filesystem. Can you `ls` the directory to see if it gives an error? Also you haven't answered Otomo's question about the filesize.

Comment: if you had a plaintext file with info, changing the extension to php would result in a bad php file if you dont add some markup to it. also, have you tried removing the @'s before your includes to see if some other errors are involved?

Comment: <?php @includes('images/includes/site_links/links.php'); ?> rename includes to > include and make sure that the file exists at that location.

Comment: *"I have PHP [...] 4.4.9 on the server"* Wow — I don't think this is the issue but it's something you'll want to fix immediately if possible.

Comment: Its a free host, I think the PHP version will be upgraded upon choosing the paid version... The size of the file is 1.2kb